# CanvasJS Multiple Charts

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, canvasjs

Im working with a quiet nice little js tool called CanvasJS. It works perfectly fine until I needed it to display more than one Chart at once.

Right now it just displays the last entry. Enerything else is being ignored. I tried pretty much everything, but simply can't figure out why it wont't work.

If someone has an idea how I coud make it mork propperly, I would be verry verry happy if you let me know.

VERSION: CanvasJS – v1.0 GA

Type: Line

Script: http://pastebin.com/hXVBkS8E

Tool URL: canvasjs.com

EDIT:
By the way the solution sugested by [@Sunil Urs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159764/sunil-urs) works perfectly!

```
style="width: 80%; height:400px;"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/ZXh5y/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your code and charts are actually rendering. But, all div elements are overlapping on top of each other. Just set the height for all div elements and it should work fine.

Comment: Thx for your reply. No they aren't rendert at all. the div tags exists but filled with no content. Only the last one is renderd correctly.

Comment: Here is your code working with the previously mentioned fix

http://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/ZXh5y/