# Why this Javascript Chart won't work twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I've got some charts of http://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/ and they are just wonderful! I used one of them and it worked perfectly :

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                google.charts.load("current", {packages: ["corechart"]});
                google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                function drawChart() {
                    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                        ['ip', 'quantity'],
                            @foreach($ipsWithBytesDates as $item)
                        ['{{$item['ip']}}', {{$item['counts']}}],
                        @endforeach
                        ]);

                    var options = {
                        title: 'My Daily Activities',
                        is3D: true,
                    };

                    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
                    chart.draw(data, options);
                }
            </script>
            <div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 700px; height: 350px;"></div>
```

Now i need a second chart - I've already got it from the website and copy & paste it in my code.. but this haven't worked like I want.. the second chart works but overwrites the whole first chart.

The first chart is a column chart and is at the top of my page.. the second chart should be at the bottom.. but it isn't, it every time just overwrites my first chart -- could anybody tell me why? I think it's because of the "window.onload" at the beginning of both chart.. but I haven't really worked with javascript.

second chart:

```
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                    window.onload = function () {
                        var secchart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer2",
                                {
                                    title:{
                                        text: "U.S Smartphone OS Market Share, Q3 2012",
                                        fontFamily: "Impact",
                                        fontWeight: "normal"
                                    },

                                    legend:{
                                        verticalAlign: "bottom",
                                        horizontalAlign: "center"
                                    },
                                    data: [
                                        {
                                            //startAngle: 45,
                                            indexLabelFontSize: 20,
                                            indexLabelFontFamily: "Garamond",
                                            indexLabelFontColor: "darkgrey",
                                            indexLabelLineColor: "darkgrey",
                                            indexLabelPlacement: "outside",
                                            type: "doughnut",
                                            showInLegend: true,
                                            dataPoints: [
                                                {  y: 53.37, legendText:"Android 53%", indexLabel: "Android 53%" },
                                                {  y: 35.0, legendText:"iOS 35%", indexLabel: "Apple iOS 35%" },
                                                {  y: 7, legendText:"Blackberry 7%", indexLabel: "Blackberry 7%" },
                                                {  y: 2, legendText:"Windows 2%", indexLabel: "Windows Phone 2%" },
                                                {  y: 5, legendText:"Others 5%", indexLabel: "Others 5%" }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                });
                        secchart.render();
                    }
                </script>
                <script type="text/javascript"></script>
            <div id="chartContainer2" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

source code from the chartlibary:

Comment: just ignore the @foreach..... in the first chart - thats PHP that I just needed to use at this point :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to have separate containers for each chart.  Each snippet you've pasted is using `var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",`

Try setting the 2nd chart to use a different element on your page.

```
<div id="chartContainer1" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
<div id="chartContainer2" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer1", ...
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer2", ...
```

Comment: thanks, that worked well.. now the seccond chart is there where i need it.. my new problem is now, that the first chart is just gone :o 

i havent changed the first chart at any point, I just renamed the seccond chart from "chartContainer" to "doughnutContainer"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like both of these charts are being rendered in an element called "chartContainer". In both code snippets there is a div at the bottom with this name. You should change the name of this div for at least one of the charts.

Comment: well I did - both chart div's have different names.. now the seccond one workes but the first one is just gone.. there is just a big empty place left

Comment: Ah, I think I see the problem. Same issue, only it's with the variable that stores the chart itself. Both are named "chart", try renaming one.

Comment: well I did.. the seccond chart is now: var secchart and at the bottom of the seccond chart is written:      secchart.render(); 

but my first chart is still gone :o

Comment: No problem :). I can't see anything obvious now. Can you get the source code for the chart library? Might be helpful to put a breakpoint in the render() function to see if it's being called correctly. Also, do you see any errors in the javascript console in your browser?

Comment: there arent any error codes in my browser :/ I updated my question with my current code and with a link with the source code of the chart libary!

Comment: well I think there is no need for posting the source code :o cause the first chart works perfectly as the seccond chart wasnt there.. the seccond now worked perfect but the first one is gone.. thats why I cant imagine any function isnt right defined.. i mean it has allready worked :) 

but here is the link for the seccond chart:

http://canvasjs.com/editor/?id=http://canvasjs.com/example/gallery/doughnut/election_result/

Comment: Sorry, I can't see anything more that might help. I did a quick google search though and I saw several examples of multiple charts on one page, including the following SO question. The result of that question was that there was some overlapping HTML elements. Other than that I'm afraid I have no more ideas. Link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106205/canvasjs-multiple-charts

Comment: i've found the mistake :) it was because of the onload function :) my code havent load both of them :o it is enough just to have a single time this function in the code :)